# Is there a way to import into an openerp tree view like in v5?

Tags: import, odoo

In version 5 of openerp, you could import directly into an embedded tree view in a form page (eg import sales lines on a sales order). Is there any way to do this in version 6 or 7? It was useful functionality.

[image: version 5 sales order page]

There is of course a workaround by importing sub-objects (eg import sales order with "line_ids/name" etc) but it is not very user friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is NO, as with v6 this feature was dropped. 
Reason is with v5, you have to first save Main record (or it will be saved automatically on clicking o2m widget) and then you can add o2m records which was used to map newly added (imported data) with current object.

Now with new version, main record is not saved no o2m records are saved until and unless you save it using "Save" button. so import stuff can't work over here.

Comment: Interesting, good explanation. But you can add o2m records before you save in v6/7 so why would you not be able to import them?

Comment: because O2M requires associating it with a existing record, which is not available without saving parent record.

Comment: If you have an editable tree view on a new object and you add records there, it doesn't have the ID of the parent record either though does it? (I guess this is a forum discussion - happy with your answer :)